# Parallel transport of general tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Everything is happening on a Riemannian manifold $(N,g)$ with the Levi-Civita connection in the following discussion. In a paper I'm reading, the author defines on a codimension 2 submanifold, $M\subset N$, a metric $\omega$ where the then claims that $M$ is $\omega$ is defined on the boundary of a tubular nbhd of $M$, namely onto the hypersurface $M'_r$ where
$$M'_r:=\{x\in N: d_g(x,M)=r \}.$$
My question is that am I correct to assume that he parallelly transported $\omega$ from $M$ to $M_r'$ along the radial directions? I was aware that you can parallel transport vectors, but I wasn't aware that you could for general tensors. Can you also parallelly transport functions?

Comment: Can you give the reference of that paper?

Comment: It's "Positive scalar curvature with skeleton singularities" by Li and Mantoulidis, which you can find on Chao Li's website. Specifically, I'm referring one of the steps in the proof of Proposition 3.2. where my question comes from $\sigma,\omega$ (for example) the formula 3.10.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna have a look at this

Comment: Great, thanks Didier! I have a few other questions from that proposition which I may post later.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, there is no parallel transport involved but an identification in some natural coordinates.
Let me summarize what I think I have understand from a quick reading of the paper (available at [arXiv:1708.08211](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.08211.pdf)).
I would be happy to receive any comment regarding any misunderstanding from anyone.
If a specialist has a really important remark, may they feel free to edit this answer to fix any fundamental error.

Let $N$ be a codimension $2$ submanifold of the Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$.
Consider $\nu N$ the normal bundle of $N$ in $M$, that is
$$
\nu N = \{(x,v) \in N\times T_xM \mid v \in v \perp T_xN \}.
$$
It is a rank $2$ vector bundle over $N$.
The normal exponential map is the map
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
E\colon & \nu N & \longrightarrow & M \\
& (x,v) & \longmapsto & \exp_x(v)
\end{array}.
$$
Fix $x\in N$.
It can be shown that $dE(x,0) \colon T_xN \oplus \nu_xN \to T_xM$ is the identity map, and from the inverse function Theorem there exists an open neighbourhood $V_x\subset N$ of $x$ in $N$, and a real number $r_0>0$, such that $E$ induces a diffeomorphism from $\{(x,v) \in \nu N \mid x\in V_x, |v|_g < r_0\}$ onto its image $U_x$.
By shrinking $V_x$ into a smaller neighbourhood, one can find a local trivialization
$$
\nu N|_{V_x} \simeq V_x \times \Bbb R^2,
$$
and therefore we have a diffeomorphism (denoting $B(0,r_0)$ the open disk of radius $r_0$ in $\Bbb R^2$):
$$
V_x \times B(0,r_0) \longrightarrow U_x.
$$
If $\{x^1,\ldots,x^{n-2}\}$ are coordinates for $N$ on $V_x$ and $(r,\theta)$ are polar coordinates on $B(0,r_0)$, then $\{x^1,\ldots,x^{n-2},r,\theta\}$ are now coordinates on $U_x$.
It *seems* that the hypothesis of the authors (see equation (3.4), page 9 of the arXiv version) are that in this coordinates system, the metric reads
$$
g|_{\{x^1,\ldots,x^{n-2},r,\theta\}} = f^2 dr^2 + r^2 (d\theta + \sigma)^2 + \omega|_{\{x^1,\ldots,x^{n-2}\}},
$$
where $f$ is a function on $U_x$, $\sigma$ is a $1$-form on $\Bbb S^1$, and $\omega$ is a metric on $N$ (the restriction of $g$).

In fact, it seems that the authors assume that this can be done globally: the normal bundle of $N$ seems to be assumed trivial (we say that $N$ is co-orientable), and the whole tubular neighbourhood $U$ of $N$ seems to be endowed with a global trivialization
$$
N \times B(0,r_0) \longrightarrow U,
$$
so that equation (3.4) defines a metric on all of $U$.
(To be perfectly rigorous, I should have consider polar coordinates with $0<r<r_0$ instead of $0\leqslant r<r_0$, and the diffeomorphism is in fact bewteen $N \times (B(0,r_0)\setminus \{0\})$ and $U\setminus N$.)

Comment: Hi Didier, first of all thank you so much for taking the time to look through this for me. I greatly appreciate it. Some remarks. First, in definition 2.2 (Edge Singularities), both $\sigma,\omega$ are defined on $N$, and then the authors say that actually the metric g, similar to the one you wrote down, is defined in $U-N$ with the same $\omega,\sigma$ appearing. In view of this, could you say a bit on how you took $\sigma$ to be a 1-form on $S^1$? Second could you point out where they assumed co-orientability? As I understand, $N$ is a general co-dimensional 2 submanifold.

Comment: Hi @ZackFox. In that case, it seems that $\sigma$ is a $1$-form on $N$, and not on $\Bbb S^1$. I *presume* co-orientability is *implicitly* assumed to use a global trivialization $\nu N |_{|v|_g< r_0}\simeq N\times B(0,r_0)$, but I would have to think more about it